# Access nested params in Rails - attributes from checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm trying to access the users array that I get from a check box, to add to an HABTM association between a Reservation and User model.

The params hash is the following:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vx0dTg8Q2XpyFcXpmmiwbwtFwNiRO25CQImGBasArDZjEbOmjh2lkBSdQGl8Z2Sgr7+kF2qveergEFjZr63AHQ==", "reservation"=>{"name"=>"daads", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"", "number_people"=>"1", "duration"=>"1", "address"=>"", "description"=>"", "users"=>["", "3", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Create Reservation", "date"=>"2016-10-30", "hour"=>"01:30", "id"=>"1"}
```

My method code is:

```
def add_reservation
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
  init_date = params[:date].to_s + " " + params[:hour].to_s + ":00"

  @reservation.date = init_date.to_datetime
  @reservation.date_end = (@reservation.date.to_time + @reservation.duration.hours).to_datetime


  user_reservation_params[:users].each do |u|
    @reservation.users << u
  end

  @business.reservations << @reservation

  flash[:success] = "Reservation added!"
  redirect_to business_path(@business)
end
```

My helpers are defined as:

```
private
def reservation_params
  params.require(:reservation).permit(:name, :email, :address, :phone, :duration, :date, :date_end, :number_people, :description)
end

private
def user_reservation_params
  params.require(:reservation).permit(:users => [])
end
```

The way I'm currently accessing the users part of params hash gives me empty variables... How am I supposed to access those values?

Comment: try adding `:users => []` as strong param on `reservation_params` and access it with `reservation_params['user']` to access users on your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them simply as `params[:reservation][:users]`, no need to use strong params for this, since they are not used in mass assignment.